# Getting error suggesting that I should "Use rotate(app, ...) to call this function.". How should I format my code?

Tags: matlab, rotation

This is what my code for the function "Rotate" looks like:
The error I get here is: **Use app as the first argument for 'rotate'**.

```
    function o = rotate(centre, verts, theta)
        R = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) cosd(theta)];
        c = centre - vertsl
        c = c*R;
        o = centre + c;
        
    end
```

I get an error suggesting that I should **"Use rotate(app, ...) to call this function."**. How can I fix this? It's not running.
This is what the code looks when I call it under the callback function of the buttton:

```
% Do the rotation of the circles
verts = rotate(root, verts, theta);
sc1_loc = rotate(root, [root(1) + h, root(2)], theta);
sc2_loc = rotate(root, [root(1) - h, root(2)], theta);
bc1_loc = rotate(root, [root(1), root(2) + k], theta);
bc2_loc = rotate(root, [root(1), root(2) - k], theta);
sc1_loc_straight = rotate(root, [root(1) + h, root(2)], 0);
sc2_loc_straight = rotate(root, [root(1) - h, root(2)], 0);
bc1_loc_straight = rotate(root, [root(1), root(2) + k], 0);
bc2_loc_straight = rotate(root, [root(1), root(2) - k], 0);
```

I am very new to using Matlab so please excuse any inconveniences caused.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a function called rotate in matlab that uses different input arguments, so thats the current error you are seeing.

Try renaming your function/file to something else and update the callback code to use the new function name

Comment: I am getting the same error with a different funtion too. I also used the function arcGenerator and i am getting the same prompt. How would I go about this?

Comment: what diff name? and it still talks about rotate(app ? after also changing whats in your callback to the new function anmes?